# High Mounted 3rd Brake Light Not Functioning

Tags: electrical, jetta, tdi, third-brake-light

I have a 2013 Jetta TDI with 34k. The third brake light doesn't work, I tried the flashers ... still doesn't work. I don't have a meter, so I can't tell if there's power to the wires. I did take the bulb out and ran a 9vdc battery to the leads and the light itself works. I'm stuck as to what's next? I don't want to pay a shop bookoo bucks. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Possibly a break in one of the wires into the tailgate...

Comment: IIRC, the 3rd brake light doesn't light with the flashers. It should be on a separate circuit.